# access 2007 how to return string from function into "in" statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could you please help me with this problem?

I have a `ComboBox` in Form and I want return these values into `in` statement in SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM [Actual_list query]
WHERE ((([Actual_list LSC query].[place]) In (([Forms]![Internal forms]![Places].Value))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to build your SQL in VBA. You can get the list from the combo.

This is for a numeric list, a list of strings needs quotes.

```
For Each itm In Me.PlacesListbox.ItemsSelected
  listofvalues = listofvalues & "," & Me.PlacesListbox.Column(0, itm)
Next

listofvalues = Mid(listofvalues,2)

sSQL="SELECT * FROM [Actual_list query] " _
    & "WHERE [Actual_list LSC query].[place] In (" & listofvalues & ")"
```